# how to request and get only partial data from json using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to get only partial data from api in clientside and make other data to display only scroll to bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function  () {
            var out = "";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'myapi url',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var books = data.books;
                    console.log(books);
                    var out = "";
                    var i;
                    for(i=0;i < books.length;i++){
                        out +="<div class='test'>"+"<div>"+books[i].id+"</div>"+"<div>"+books[i].title+"</div>"+"</div>";
                    }
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = out;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        });
```

For eg: I have 20 datas,Only 10 datas should be requested and fetched first and remaining datas should fetched only after scroll to bottom.

html:

```
<div id="demo">
        <ul id="content" class="list">

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: This depends totally on the API. It might or might not support pagination. Remember: your response has to be valid json or xml to be parseable on client side. It is not usable if it is a fraction.

Comment: API which i am using doesn't support pagination.Is there any way can we limit the data from client side and load data from API and remaining datas on scroll increment

Comment: Your only option is to keep the result in memory do the pagination by rendering only a page of corresponding elements.